# Change the background of a specific td row of a dynamic table using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this dynamic table:

```
<table id="thetable">


            <tr> 

                <th class="th2">&nbsp;&nbsp;Id&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
                <th class="th2">&nbsp;&nbsp;Attivo&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
                <th class="th2">&nbsp;&nbsp;Capacità&nbsp;&nbsp;</th> 
                <th class="th2">&nbsp;&nbsp;Zona&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
                <th class="th2">&nbsp;&nbsp;Stato&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>

         </tr> 

            <tr style="cursor:pointer"  ng-repeat="staffdispenser in staffdispensers">  

        <td ng-click="changePath(staffdispenser.dispenser.iddispenser)"> {{ staffdispenser.dispenser.iddispenser }}</td>  
        <td ng-click="changePath(staffdispenser.dispenser.iddispenser)"> {{ staffdispenser.dispenser.stateOn }}</td> 
        <td ng-click="changePath(staffdispenser.dispenser.iddispenser)"> {{ staffdispenser.dispenser.capacity.type }}</td>
        <td ng-click="changePath(staffdispenser.dispenser.iddispenser)"> {{ staffdispenser.dispenser.geoArea.city }}</td>  
        <td ng-click="changePath(staffdispenser.dispenser.iddispenser)"> {{ (count[$index]*100)/(staffdispenser.dispenser.capacity.depthForSection*staffdispenser.dispenser.capacity.nsections) }}%</td>  

        </tr>  

        </table>
```

I want to change td background for a specific row, that rows where "count[$index]*100)/(staffdispenser.dispenser.capacity.depthForSection*staffdispenser.dispenser.capacity.nsections)" is less than 0.5

This is my view:

[image]

I want something like that:

[image]

Comment: use ng-class with that condition in it?

Comment: can you show me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you ever heard of [`ngClass`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)?

You can add it to your elements like this

```
<td ng-class="{'yellow-background': (count[$index]100)/(staffdispenser.dispenser.capacity.depthForSectionstaffdispenser.dispenser.capacity.nsections) < 0.5 }"></td>
```

Although your conditional is not syntactically valid. What is the `100` supposed to be?

```
count[$index]100)/(staffdispenser.dispenser.capacity.depthForSectionstaffdispenser.dispenser.capacity.nsections)
```

Comment: [$index]*100 ..but nothing happenens

Comment: You need to make sure that all the variables in your conditional are in scope and that you actually have a `yellow-background` class in your CSS

Answer (score 1):

Alfonso,

Consider looking here for an example of ngClass:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

You can apply this to the  element to dynamically apply the class.

Example:

```html
            <tr style="cursor:pointer"  ng-repeat="staffdispenser in staffdispensers" ng-class="{'special-row-color': staffdispenser.isMyCondition == true}">  

        <td ng-click="changePath(staffdispenser.dispenser.iddispenser)"> {{ staffdispenser.dispenser.iddispenser }}</td>  
        <td ng-click="changePath(staffdispenser.dispenser.iddispenser)"> {{ staffdispenser.dispenser.stateOn }}</td> 
        <td ng-click="changePath(staffdispenser.dispenser.iddispenser)"> {{ staffdispenser.dispenser.capacity.type }}</td>
        <td ng-click="changePath(staffdispenser.dispenser.iddispenser)"> {{ staffdispenser.dispenser.geoArea.city }}</td>  
        <td ng-click="changePath(staffdispenser.dispenser.iddispenser)"> {{ (count[$index]*100)/(staffdispenser.dispenser.capacity.depthForSection*staffdispenser.dispenser.capacity.nsections) }}%</td>  

        </tr>
```

I would recommend making a function inside the controller for that conditional you want to apply.

Comment: I'm not managing to make it work, can you do me a practical example and banal?

Answer (score 1):

First, I think you have way too much logic in your Angular `{{ }}` expressions, and you should offload that to a controller.

You said:

> I want to change td background for a specific row, that rows where
>   "count[$index]100)/(staffdispenser.dispenser.capacity.depthForSectionstaffdispenser.dispenser.capacity.nsections)"
>   is less than 0.5

So your `<td>` should look like this:

```
<td ng-class="getClass($index)">{{ myLogicHere }}</td>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.getClass = function(index) {
  var value = count[index]100)/(staffdispenser.dispenser.capacity.depthForSectionstaffdispenser.dispenser.capacity.nsections;
  return value < .5 ? 'highlight-class' : '';
};
```

Of course, adjust to whatever values/properties/logic your controller has.